# pip install pyodbc in python 3.x

Tags: python, pip

***Sorry new to python***.
I have installed python 2.7 and python 3.5.

2.7 is the default one. I want to install **pyodbc** to 3.5 so i open the 3.5 python folder and i `pip install odbc`.

The problem is that it is being installed on 2.7 even though i am in 3.5 folder.
What can i do for that?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do explicitly tell to use python3

```
C:\>path\to\python3.exe -m pip install -U pyodbc
```

or, you can use virtulenv

```
C:\>path\to\python3.exe -m venv yourEnv
path\to\yourEnv\bin\activate
pip install -U pyodbc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see whether it is working or not

pip3 install odbc

Answer (score 1):

The `pip` executable you use to install `pyodbc` is the one frome version `2.7`, but the `python`executable is from version `3.5`.

To execute the right `pip` executable you have several options:

**Option 1**

```
python -m pip install pyodbc
```

This ensures you will always use the right `pip` version with respect to the current `python` version you are using.

**Option 2**

Figure out which `pip` is executed, when you just type `pip`. This commands may help you:

- `pip --version`
- `where.exe pip` (as you are on Windows)
- Looking at you environment variable (e.g. PATH variable)

Comment: Side note: it does not matter in which directory are when you execute something. It depends on where the OS looks for the executable. This is usually set in the **PATH** variable of you environment variables.